# Thread Safety of files

Tags: java, multithreading, file

I have many applications writing to my file in concurrent in java.I want to make this operation concurrent and also want my file to preserve order.I have 
Thread 1 writing from website 1

Thread 2 writing from website 2

Thread 3 writing from website 3

And i want to preserve order.

How can i do this
Thanks

Comment: To be more specific: Thread3 cannot write to the file while Thread2 has not written ?

Comment: 3 threads are writing to my file concurrently.But i want the data to be consistent.The data from website 1 grouped  together in my file and website 2 grouped together.

Comment: What is about N files for N threads ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use regular synchronization mechanism. Create file repository that contains references to java.io.File objects. It will expose API like getFile(String path). Every time you want to access file do the following:

```
File file = FileRepository.getFile("foo.txt");
synchronized(file) {
  // perform any manipulations. 
}
```

Other way to synchronize access to files is:

```
FileChannel.lock()
```

Comment: Is `FileChannel.lock()` for thread mutual exclusion or process mutual exclusion? Will it work for both?

Comment: It's for process mutual exclusion, in the same jvm, you'll get an `OverlappingFileLockException`

Answer (score 6):

Use a [Queue](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Queue_%28data_structure%29) to represent operations to the file and make sure you take from the queue in the appropriate order (first-in-first-out).  You could treat this as a [producer consumer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer-consumer_problem) problem.  You have multiple threads grabbing data, and a single consumer writing that data to disk.

Comment: how can i maintain the order of contents?

Comment: The Queue keeps track of that, it's a sorted data structure. Using Java queue (http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html) items are added at the end and removed from the head, so the oldest items get's removed first. So remove one after another and put it into a file and you get the same order as the items arrived.

Comment: yes, and i think this is his problem: when t3 arrives before t1 (t3 finished reading before t1) then t3 should be pushed back in the queue (if queue is the right answer).

Comment: Order should be maintained by the queue.  I guess it depends on the write pattern that you are using to dump data to disk.  If each thread just produces one giant lump, then a queue will maintain order.  If each thread produces lots of small pieces then a queue is still possible, but more difficult to work with.  You'd have a queue per thread, but only one thread queue would be able to work with the file system at any point in time.

Comment: You're right, the demand for grouping was added later I assumed order to be by time only.

Comment: As PeterMmm has suggested, N files for N threads and merging at the end is probably the most efficient approach if you're writing big data.  If your data is small enough, just store it in memory and write it at the end.